# Using ImagePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. I want to make an app that has an image picker.

I found this article: https://ishtiz.com/swiftui/image-picker-in-swiftui

It says:

> To implement an image picker in SwiftUI, you can use the `ImagePicker` struct provided by the SwiftUI framework. This struct has a `pickImage()` method that presents the image picker to the user and returns the selected image as a UIImage object.

Providing this example code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var image: UIImage?
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      if image != nil {
        Image(uiImage: image!)
          .resizable()
          .scaledToFit()
      }
      Button("Select Image") {
        self.image = ImagePicker.pickImage()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added the code to my project but it doesn’t build:

> Cannot find 'ImagePicker' in scope

Do I need to import something?

Comment: Apple has a worked example https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/bringing_photos_picker_to_your_swiftui_app

Comment: Thank you very much. This shows the usage of `PhotosPicker`. I would like to use `ImagePicker` that is referenced in the article.

Comment: The best way to find out is to [search it on apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=ImagePicker). Do you find it? If not, it's time to learn not to trust everything from a random blog.

Comment: But it seem like a nice blog.

Comment: @DarrenJackson Maybe it is. Maybe there are valuable information on the site. But it should not be treated as source of truth.

Comment: There has never been a built-in system that works like this. My guess is that the article was written with ChatGPT and is just wrong.

Comment: The name of the blog should say it all. It is nonsense.

Comment: What about the name? It derives from the bloggers name "Ishtiak Achmed", developer of HabitOn, based in Munich. Here is his LinkedIn profile https://www.linkedin.com/in/ishtiakahmed/

Answer (score 5):

try **import PhotosUI**

For iOS Versions lower than 16.0
you can refers [tutorial](https://designcode.io/swiftui-advanced-handbook-imagepicker)

For iOS 16.0 + you can use **[PhotoPicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/bringing_photos_picker_to_your_swiftui_app)**

```
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct PhotosPickerDemo: View {
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem? = nil
    @State private var selectedImageData: Data? = nil

    var body: some View {
        PhotosPicker(
            selection: $selectedItem,
            matching: .images,
            photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                Text("Select a photo")
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedItem) { newItem in
                Task {
                    // Retrieve selected asset in the form of Data
                    if let data = try? await newItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                        selectedImageData = data
                    }
                }
            }

        if let selectedImageData,
           let uiImage = UIImage(data: selectedImageData) {
            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I customise its view?

Comment: you can implement it by calling PhotosPickerDemo() where you want to add image and you can change Text or Frame accordingly.